# Using sketches with either Apache Beam or Apache Flink in python

Tags: python-3.x, streaming, apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming

I want to use [KLL sketch](https://datasketches.apache.org/docs/Quantiles/KllSketchVsTDigest.html) for a stream application. The catch is that KLL sketch is a stateful computation and thus not idempotent. Can this be implemented using in Beam or Flink, preferably in Python?

Apache Datasketch says [Integration efforts have started with Apache Flink and Apache Impala. There is also interest from Apache Beam](https://incubator.apache.org/clutch/datasketches.html). What is the main difficulty? Most sketches use primitive types and arrays internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [state and timers](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/) to use this in a streaming Beam Pipeline.

Comment: They are not similar to KLL sketch.